# Creating a list of variables and calling them later bash

Tags: bash

I want to create a list of variables,so later i can do a prompts for users and if their input is matching any variable within that list, I want to use that variable to execute it within a command, for example:

var1=a
var2=b
...
read input
(user chooses var1) command $var1,rest of the command

The biggest problem is that this list will be huge, what would be the best solution? Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure bash doesn't work this way, but I could be wrong.

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: I would need to know more about your specific application to offer any advice.

Comment: So lets say i have a firmware repo, and i will have users in multiple regions downloading that firmware, i want to prompt the user for the region and based on his input i want to download specific firmware, i hope i explained well.

Comment: Separate the functionality. Put functionality that belongs together in the same script, and the things that are outside of the scope put into a different file and just call them as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the associative array feature in `bash` 4 or later.

```
declare -A foo

foo[us]="United States"
foo[uk]="Great Britain"

read -p "Region? " region
echo "${foo[$region]}"
```

If the value of `$region` is not a defined key, then `${foo[$region]}` will be treated like any unset variable.

Comment: You are a life saviour. Thank you so much :D